# No module named 'netCDF4'

Tags: python, pip, spyder, netcdf

I am currently working with netCDF data in the Spyder IDE, however when I try to import 'Dataset' from the module

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
```

it is giving me the following error: "No module named 'netCDF4'". I already installed the module but I guess it is not in the same environment where I installed spyder. How can I fix this? If it helps solving my question. When I try to install netCDF4 in the spyder console using 'pip install netCDF4' it gives the following error:

"/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/MacOS/python: No module named pip
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages."

I looked up the path of the module: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/netCDF4'

and I guess the path for spyder is:
'/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/MacOS/python'

How can I make sure that they are both located in the same environment?

I tried to look up the issue, however nothing really solved my problem.

Would be glad if anyone could help me out.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from cftime import numb2date
import tifffile as tifffile

# define arrays
XNR=[] # number
Xdt=[] # time 
YGP=[] # GPP
YPP=[] # PPFD

# read csv file and extract column 0 (timestemp), PPFD (column 54) and GPP (column 312)
# take a file from FLUXNET for validation of the GPP model 
with open(r'/Users/janoschbeer/Documents/Studium/ESS/ES_Observ/Assignments/Lab6/FLX_SJ-Adv_FLUXNET2015_SUBSET_2011-2014_1-4/FLX_SJ-Adv_FLUXNET2015_SUBSET_DD_2011-2014_1-4.csv') as csv:
    lines = csv.readlines()
    for i in range(2, len(lines)):
        tmp=lines[i].split(",")
        XNR.append(float(i))
        Xdt.append(float(tmp[0]))
        YGP.append(float(tmp[312]))
        YPP.append(float(tmp[54]))
```

Comment: You could try anaconda or miniconda python, and install both spyder and netcdf4 into the same conda environment.

Comment: The problem is that you don't have netcdf installed in your python environment.

Even if it is of topic, you should use Xarray, and not the module netCDF, because it is deprecated.